# interacting with JavaFX network service in a GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, fxml

I am transitioning from writing a java Swing application to JavaFX to write a modern java based GUI application.

I would like to know the best approach to create a network based reusable threading service.  The way I coded up the network service was to use a controller class (generated from the FXML via the Net-beans GUI).  I put the threading logic here via a private Service member named '`transmitter`' and I wired up the start/stop logic via the Start/Stop button's event callback.
The network based thread is implemented as a javafx Service - I did this since I would like to restart the service/thread whenever the destination address changes.  This seems to be the recommended approach in place of a stand alone Task.

The network service is very simple right now, all it does is use some GUI widgets to configure a packet to transmit to a host/port once a second.  I need to restart the service only if the host/port widget changes, however if the network service is running, I would like to modify the packet without interrupting/restarting the DatagramSocket. The place where I have questions and require some guidance are:

1. What is the recommended approach to threading a network thread in an
   FXML based application?  An example would be greatly appreciated.
2. How do I safely communicate changes from GUI widgets (via their
   action performed callbacks) to the running service class?

Shown below are the most relevant parts of my controller class:

```
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author johnc
 */
public class OpMessageServerController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Text mCurrentDateTimeText;
    @FXML
    private Label mApplicationStatus;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<DiscreteStatus> mPofDS;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<PhaseOfFlightFMS> mPofFMS;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<DiscreteStatus> mTailNumberDS;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<DiscreteStatus> mConfigTableDS;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<DiscreteStatus> mDateTimeDS;
    @FXML
    private TextField mEpicPN;
    @FXML
    private TextField mConfigTablePNHash;
    @FXML
    private TextField mTailNumber;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<DiscreteStatus> mTopLevelPNDS;
    @FXML
    private Button mStartStopButton;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> mDLMUHostSpec;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox connectionStatusC1;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox wsuConnectionStatus;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox connectionStatusC4;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox connectionStatusC3;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox connectionStatusC2;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox dlmuwConnectionStatus;

    private Service<Void> transmitter;



    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {        
        mPofDS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DiscreteStatus.values()));
        mPofDS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        mPofFMS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(PhaseOfFlightFMS.values()));
        mPofFMS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        mTailNumberDS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DiscreteStatus.values()));
        mTailNumberDS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        mConfigTableDS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DiscreteStatus.values()));
        mConfigTableDS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        mDateTimeDS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DiscreteStatus.values()));
        mDateTimeDS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        mTopLevelPNDS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(DiscreteStatus.values()));
        mTopLevelPNDS.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
//      mDLMUHostSpec.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
//          FXCollections.observableArrayList("localhost:1234", "192.168.200.2:1234")));

        // add event handler here to update the current date/time label
        // this should also update the transmit datastructure
        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
            mCurrentDateTimeText.setText(currentDateTime.format(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk:mm:ss uuuu")));  
        }));  

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);  
        timeline.play();

        // create a service.
        transmitter = new Service() {
            @Override 
            protected Task createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override 
                    protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                        updateMessage("Running...");
                        updateProgress(0, 10);
                        DatagramSocket sock = null;
                        while (!isCancelled()) {
                            try {
                                if (sock == null) {
                                    DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();
                                }
                            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(OpMessageServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                            //Block the thread for a short time, but be sure
                            //to check the InterruptedException for cancellation
                            OpSupportMessage opSupportMessage = new OpSupportMessage(
                                DiscreteStatus.NormalOperation, 
                                PhaseOfFlightFMS.Cruise, 
                                DiscreteStatus.NormalOperation, 
                                "TAILNUM",
                                DiscreteStatus.NormalOperation);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            String[] specParts = mDLMUHostSpec.getValue().split(":");
                            if (specParts.length == 2) {
                                try {
                                    opSupportMessage.write(bos);
                                    byte[] buff = bos.toByteArray();
                                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                                        buff, buff.length, InetAddress.getByName(
                                        specParts[0]), Integer.parseInt(specParts[1]));
                                    mSocket.send(packet);
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                                    if (isCancelled()) {
                                        updateMessage("Cancelled");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }                        
                        updateMessage("Cancelled");
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void succeeded() {
                        System.out.println("Scanning completed.");
                    }

                    @Override 
                    protected void failed() {
                        System.out.println("Scanning failed.");
                    }

                    @Override 
                    protected void running() {
                        System.out.println("Scanning started.");
                    }

                    @Override 
                    protected void cancelled() {
                         System.out.println("Scanning cancelled.");
                    }                    

                    private void DatagramSocket() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        mApplicationStatus.textProperty().bind(transmitter.messageProperty());

    };

@FXML
private void startStopButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (!transmitter.isRunning()) {
        transmitter.reset();
        transmitter.start();
    }                
}

 …

}
```

Comment: Surely you don't mean to have your GUI application providing network services on behalf of clients on the network?  What would you want the GUI on the server for?

Comment: @scottb no this is a simple gui client application containing a UDP transmitter thread, I simply need to be able to control the packets going out and the contents of these packets.  One of the GUI controls "mDLMUHostSpec" contains an editable ip/port and the other controls are all to configure the packet contents, if the ip/port changes then I need to stop and restart the existing service.  If the other parameters in the GUI change (that affect the datagram that client service transmits (not to be confused with a server as I think you might have interpreted)), these need to be safely updated.

Comment: I did a proof of concept of a JavaFX app with a web socket based communication [javafx-websocket-test](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test).  Perhaps some of the concepts from there might help you, though I do recall the seemingly simple Java web socket API did contain a few gotchas.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the proof of concept application, this will be quite useful, however one thing that is a bit obscure is how one can safely communicate GUI changes to the running service thread safely.  It appears that the HelloService uses a 'name' simple string property to communicate changes from the GUI to the service before it is started.  I wonder how one might communicate UI changes to a running background service in a thread safe manner.  Via some sort or message api perhaps?

Comment: One refactoring you might consider here is having the task created by the service perform a *single* send of the message to the server. The service itself can of course maintain the connection. Since `Service.createTask` is executed on the FX Application Thread, it can safely access the UI elements, create an immutable message object, and then let a task send the message. Then you can let your timeline restart the service on a regular basis, or (probably better) use a `ScheduledService`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Background*

This answer is based upon a collection of comments on the question, it rambles a bit, does not provide a solution targeted at the code in the question and does not address some of the concepts in the question such as a low level UDP socket based communication system - apologies for that.

*Sample Solution Project*

I did a proof of concept of a JavaFX app using web socket based communication: [javafx-websocket-test](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test). Perhaps some of the concepts from there might help you, in particular the [client JavaFX Task and Service code](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jewelsea/websocket/sample/client) and the [sample client application and controller](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jewelsea/websocket/sample) that uses it.

The project does demonstrate, in an executable implementation, some of the communication principles outlined in [Adam Bien's article on JavaFX Integration Strategies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html) that James_D linked, for example:

1. Setting up a web socket endpoint within a JavaFX service.
2. Wrapping each communication interaction in an async JavaFX Task.
3. Using async event callbacks to shunt success and failure results back to the UI.

Additionally the example shows interaction between the network service and the JavaFX UI, with the JavaFX UI making async requests to the service and processing async responses from it.

I do recall the seemingly simple Java web socket API did contain a few gotchas.  It is just a proof of concept, so be careful of using it as the basis for a robust network service.

*Commentary and thoughts*

This is actually an invariably tricky question to answer IMO, due to these reasons:

1. There are many forms of network communication, some of which are suited to different applications.
2. There is (currently) no standard or best practice of integrating network services with JavaFX applications.
3. Providing a robust network connection with UI status monitoring and exception handling is often not as straight-forward as it might seem and is easy to get wrong.

There are many subtleties to be dealt with, such as:

- What to do in the event of a communication failure?
- What to do if the application issues requests at a faster rate than the network or server can process?
- What happens if the user shuts down the application while messages are outstanding?
- How to ensure that the UI is not frozen while lengthy communication processes occur?
- How to provide UI feedback that lengthy network processing is on-going?
- What underlying communication technology is being used?
- Is the underlying communication stateful or stateless?
- Is the communication non-blocking and event driven or blocking?
- How to serialize and deserialize data for transmission?

Even though a one-size fits all communication model would be difficult, a "standard" communication model could be adapted which fits many needs. For example something similar to [http ajax calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) in the browser based network model or [NetConnections for flash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html).  Those seem to function well enough for a wide variety of needs.  Though of course, they aren't optimal for everything, otherwise alternate systems such as web sockets or http live streaming would not have been created.

Ideally, there would be a single, standardized API like [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for JavaFX client => server communication, but I haven't yet seen anybody create a JavaFX equivalent of that kind of API.

Unlike the rest of the core JavaFX APIs, such standardized high-level interfaces for network communication don't exist in an off-the-shelf form at the moment. However, there are plenty of libraries and functions available to act as the basic building blocks for developing your own service; perhaps even too many to reasonably process.

Note that most higher level network protocol libraries, such as a [Tyrus web socket implementation](https://tyrus.java.net) or the [Apache HTTP components](https://hc.apache.org) underlying a [JAX-RS provider](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html) have their own internal thread-pools for communication. Systems like [netty](http://netty.io) are based upon [nio](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) and are event driven rather than thread managed.  What your JavaFX network client service is one of these two things:

- For [non-blocking I/O](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) it is issuing async calls, hooking into the response events and relaying them back to JavaFX via [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).
- For blocking I/O, it spawning a thread with a Task or Service with either an implicit or explicit executor service pool to manage the UI interaction but not the actual network comms.

A key and confusing thing is that the JavaFX application code should always perform the network communication in an async manner.  For non-blocking I/O the call is already async, so no wrapper task is necessarily required.  For blocking I/O, you don't want to block the UI thread, so the Task wrapper running in it's own thread prevents that occurring.

One would think this would make the non-blocking I/O calls simpler, but it doesn't really, as the JDK's non-blocking I/O API is quite low level and is pretty tricky to code to.  It isn't really appropriate for high level application code.

Generally, application code is better off using a higher level library such as JAX-RS, web sockets or akka (or, preferably, a layer on top of them) which internally manage the details of the communication in either a blocking or non-blocking fashion AND provide an event driven API for sending and receiving messages.  The individual message events can be wrapped in a JavaFX [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for async processing.  So, from the JavaFX application point of view, everything is event driven, nothing is blocking, and the same application API works regardless of the underlying communication protocol and blocking/non-blocking communication infrastructure.

> thanks for the proof of concept application, this will be quite useful, however one thing that is a bit obscure is how one can safely communicate GUI changes to the running service thread safely. It appears that the HelloService uses a 'name' simple string property to communicate changes from the GUI to the service before it is started.  I wonder how one might communicate UI changes to a running background service in a thread safe manner. Via some sort or message api perhaps?

A [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) with a fixed max-size which rejects additional requests when the queue is full can be used for communication from JavaFX thread based code to a consumer service. It is a reasonably elegant solution to the classic [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Of course, you could just skip the blocking queue and keep creating async tasks ad-nauseum, which is fine for low volume communication, but could lead to a starvation of limited thread resources for high volume communication.  One standard way to handle that is to use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) from [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) which manages a thread pool.  The thread pool for the executor service can be defined to be [bounded to a max number of threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) and internally use an unbounded queue where messages pile up if all threads are busy.  That way you don't need to define your own blocking queue, you just issue async service requests and they are immediately handled in threads if they can be or the requests pile up in the internal queue if they cannot.

This is actually the way that a [JavaFX Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) works:

> The Service by default uses a thread pool Executor with some unspecified default or maximum thread pool size. This is done so that naive code will not completely swamp the system by creating thousands of Threads.

and:

> If an Executor is specified on the Service, then it will be used to actually execute the service. Otherwise, a daemon thread will be created and executed. If you wish to create non-daemon threads, then specify a custom Executor (for example, you could use a ThreadPoolExecutor with a custom ThreadFactory).

More sophisticated solutions for which a simple BlockedQueue messaging is not appropriate would use a topic based message queue style solution, e.g., a Java based [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) client such as this [kaazing example](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/08/27/three-steps-to-build-a-killer-websocket-app-with-javafx/).

Getting the message info to the service is just part of the requirement, that is essentially doing an async message send.  You also need to process the response that comes back.  To do that, there are two alternatives:

1. You model each request as a separate Task, and the onSuccess and onError handlers process the task response.  Running the task within a service ensures that it is handled by an executor with a fixed thread pool backed by an internal queue for overflow.
2. You write your own long running service interface with it's own API and encapsulate a blocking queue for requests, using [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) for handling communicating results back to the UI.

To make the response handler logic dynamic and adjustable by the caller, you could pass the handler function as a lambda function to be executed on success for the original call using [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

If you wrap the call in a Task or Service, and use the onSucceeded function, you don't need the runLater call, because the implementation will ensure that the onSucceeded handler is called on the JavaFX thread once the task completes.

Note, that often the network request and response require some conversion of marshaling and unmarshaling of data to and from a serializable stream.  Some of the higher level network APIs such as the JAX-RS or web socket providers provide interfaces and utilities to do some of this work for you, often using specific libraries for different types of conversion, such as [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) for XML serialization of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for JSON serialization.

*Slightly related info and further thoughts*

This next is probably a bit off-topic, but this is an example of [BlockingQueue and Task interaction](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743), it is not a network service, but it does demonstrate use of queues within a producer/consumer situation, with a reactive UI and progress monitoring.

One other thing that would be interesting to see (at least for me), is an [Akka](http://akka.io) based solution for JavaFX client->server communication.  That seems like a nice alternative to traditional http/rest/soap/rmi calls or message queue based processing.  Akka is inherently an event based solution for fault-tolerant asynchronous concurrent communication, so it would seem a good match-up for a UI based framework such as JavaFX, allowing a developer to process at an appropriate layer of abstraction.  But I have yet to see a JavaFX based messaging client that relies on Akka.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know the best approach to create a network based
>   reusable threading service. The way I coded up the network service was
>   to use a controller class (generated from the FXML via the Net-beans
>   GUI). I put the threading logic here via a private Service member
>   named 'transmitter' and I wired up the start/stop logic via the
>   Start/Stop button's event callback.

I humbly suggest that you develop your network service and your GUI controller as separate projects.

I would have the network service running in its own container or virtual machine as a daemon/background thread.  The advantage of this organization is that it keeps your server away from the vagaries of the JavaFX event loop and application thread.  You'll want to design your service to recognize administration commands and/or interrupt requests from your controller.  You can develop your network services as REST or whatever you want without wondering how to roll this into the JavaFX application thread.

I would then have the GUI controller running as a separate GUI application either in the same process or, if remote administration is desired, in a separate JVM (and use IPC to send/receive administration messages).

TL;DR: if it were me, I would resist the temptation to program the network service as a JavaFX application.

Comment: I agree with that. Here's a [really good article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html) on how to integrate the service into your FX application. (Second time I have referenced this article on SO today...).